# numpy 2d where with constraint on each row

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape (2,N) and three constraints to filter on.

1. No value in a column may be negative
2. Row 0 must be less than a constant, say xmax
3. Row 1 must be less than a constant, say ymax

Here is what I've tried:

```
xmax, ymax = 7, 8
dst = np.linspace(-2,10,20).reshape((2,-1)).astype(np.int32)
mask = np.where((0 <= dst) & (dst[1,:] < xmax) & (dst[0,:] < ymax))
mask = np.vstack(mask).T
for p in mask:
    print(p, dst[:,p[1]])
```

Which produces

```
(array([[-2, -1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  3,  3],
   [ 4,  4,  5,  6,  6,  7,  8,  8,  9, 10]]), (2L, 10L))
(array([0, 2]), array([0, 5]))
(array([0, 3]), array([0, 6]))
(array([0, 4]), array([0, 6]))
(array([1, 0]), array([-2,  4]))  #<-- Why do I get this ??
(array([1, 1]), array([-1,  4]))  #<-- Why do I get this ??
(array([1, 2]), array([0, 5]))
(array([1, 3]), array([0, 6]))
(array([1, 4]), array([0, 6]))
```

What am I doing wrong that is producing those two unwanted results (-2,4) and (-1,4)?

Comment: `where` is only as good as the boolean array you give it.  Look at that directly.  When indexing `dst` you ignore `p[0]`.  Why?  As an aside, `np.argwhere` does `np.transpose(where...)`, producing the same 'vertical' array of indices.

Comment: thanks for the argwhere tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @hpaulj, the mistake was in the where clause. I did not realize that I could treat this as a continuous boolean array. What I learned is that if I keep the dst >= 0  check, I maintain my dimensions and then I can add two more constraints to check for less than zero explicitly on each row value.

```
xmax, ymax = 7, 8
dst = np.linspace(-2,10,20).reshape((2,-1)).astype(np.int32)
mask = np.argwhere((dst >= 0) & (dst[0,:] >= 0) & (dst[1,:] >= 0) & (dst[1,:] < xmax) & (dst[0,:] < ymax))
print(mask)
for p in mask:
    print(p, dst[:,p[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [5]: xmax, ymax = 7, 8
   ...: dst = np.linspace(-2,10,20).reshape((2,-1)).astype(np.int32)
   ...: mask = np.where((0 <= dst) & (dst[1,:] < xmax) & (dst[0,:] < ymax))
   ...: 
In [6]: mask
Out[6]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32),
 array([2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32))

In [8]: dst[mask]
Out[8]: array([0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6])
```

`mask` does select the right elements of `dst`, but from either row.

But this selects from both rows, using just part of the the `mask` info.  So it has some of the `masked` values, but also the value from the other row.

```
In [9]: dst[:,mask[1]]
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0, -2, -1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  6,  6,  4,  4,  5,  6,  6]])
In [10]: dst[0,mask[1]]
Out[10]: array([ 0,  0,  0, -2, -1,  0,  0,  0])
In [11]: dst[1,mask[1]]
Out[11]: array([5, 6, 6, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6])
```

Comment: Oh, I see. So what's the best way to do solve this? It seems like where is not what I actually want. I just realized in my self-answer that, while correct, it now has duplicates.